# Why is the navigation between questions in my quiz app not working?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am having difficulty with getting the navigation between questions working, please see: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-quiz-app**. When clicking on the next button, the questionID gets incremented by 1 and then switches back to 1 and does not navigate to the next question. I am getting this error message in Chrome Dev Tools:

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'question/2'

Not sure what I'm missing. It should work without using id, using the index of the quizData instead. Please could you help. Thank you!

In di-quiz template:

```
<button type="button" (click)="nextQuestion()">
  Next &raquo;
</button>
```

call to next question in the service:

```
nextQuestion() {
  this.quizService.nextQuestion();
}
```

in **quiz.service.ts**:

```
constructor(
  private timerService: TimerService,
  private router: Router,
  private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    /* this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.setQuestionIndex(+params.get('questionText'));
      this.question = this.getQuestion;
    }); */
}

nextQuestion() {
  this.questionID++;
  this.navigateToNextQuestion();
  this.timerService.resetTimer();
  this.increaseProgressValue();
}

navigateToNextQuestion() {
  this.router.navigate(['/question', this.questionID]);
}
```

in **quiz-routing.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IntroductionComponent } from './containers/introduction/introduction.component';
import { DependencyInjectionQuizComponent } from './containers/dependency-injection-quiz/dependency-injection-quiz.component';
import { ResultsComponent } from './containers/results/results.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'intro' },
  { path: 'intro', component: IntroductionComponent },
  { path: 'question', component: DependencyInjectionQuizComponent },
  { path: 'question/:questionID', component: DependencyInjectionQuizComponent },
  { path: 'results', component: ResultsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class QuizRoutingModule {}
```

and my data object (in **quiz.ts**) looks like:

```
export const QUIZ_DATA: Quiz = {
  milestone: 'Dependency Injection Quiz',
  summary: "Dependency Injection is extremely powerful because it is a way of providing dependencies in your code instead of hard-coding them.",
  imageUrl: 'assets/images/DIDiagram.png',
  questions: [
    {
      questionText: 'What is the objective of dependency injection?',
      options: [
        { text: 'Pass the service to the client.', correct: true },
        { text: 'Allow the client to find service.', correct: true },
        { text: 'Allow the client to build service.' },
        { text: 'Give the client part service.' }
      ],
      explanation: 'a service gets passed to the client during DI'
    },
  ...
  ]
};
```

Comment: Put a [mre] *in the question*.

Comment: I've updated the question. I'm trying to show one question per route and I'm getting the data from the quiz.ts file.

Comment: When I enter the game I have this error `this.question is undefined`

Comment: What happens in CodelabDependencyInjectionQuizComponent, can you confirm constructor is called? Are you using ActivatedRoute to grab the id?

Comment: In the CodelabDependencyInjectionQuizComponent, I have a constructor with DI services: QuizService, NavigationService and TimerService with a call from the QuizService to the NavigationService. In the NavigationService I have a constructor with private router: Router on it.  I am not using ActivatedRoute as I am avoiding the usage of id in my interface design.

Comment: I have added the first question of my quiz data object to the post (see above). Ideally "selected" should not be a field in the object but it's there for now.

Comment: getting this error in Chrome Dev Tools: ERROR Error: The requested path contains undefined segment at index 1

Comment: create stackblitz and share

Comment: I added the Stackblitz to my original post. I need it to work without using id (should use index of the quizData array instead). Please can you help.

Comment: I'm still having this issue. Also the timer isn't counting down like it did before (time gets shown when I click on an answer option), not sure what I did.

Comment: I think the countdown timer stopped working when I added OnPush.

Comment: Your project has multiple issues. You're using the ```Input``` decorator in the service. You should use it only in the components. I think your problem with routing is from the timer method where you call ```setInterval``` but you don't clear it anywhere. There you also  call ```checkIfAnsweredCorrectly``` method where you call ```navigateToNextQuestion``` method where you handle navigation.

Comment: @ionut-t, I removed the Input decorator from the fields in the services and in TimerComponent. I added clearInterval but that doesn't seem to fix the timer issue. I also tried console.log(this.timeLeft) in the setInterval, but it doesn't seem to be outputting anything to the console.

Comment: I removed this.quizInterval and now the logging of timeLeft to the console works, but the timeLeft isn't binding to the template (seems to be stuck on 20 seconds and doesn't decrement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is lot of problems with the code I saw. There are lot of `@Output` and `@Input` being used. But most of them irrelevant. I have tried to change most of the issues, but still there are few of the things that are still pending. Please have a look at the repo:

https://github.com/anooprvarrier/Quiz-example

I had upgraded all the dependency to latest version.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This looks very good and I will continue to work on it. I'm looking at the code right now. Some small issues I saw when I ran the code in my IDE, mainly with the scoreboard with the timer not resetting for each new question, badgeQuestionNumber not incrementing for each new question, correctAnswerCount becoming greater than totalQuestions. Also didn't forward to results.

Comment: Yes... Needs some modifications here and there... I will try to fix those in few days. Thank you for you response. Good to hear from you that it almost there.

Comment: I'm using your code in my project in IDE, but the timer still doesn't seem to countdown and the routing isn't working.

Comment: I have uploaded the code to my StackBlitz and it doesn't work there either. Please could you check my code. Thank you.

Comment: I've got the countdown working now in my project directory in my IDE, but the routing is still an issue, will transfer the code to StackBlitz, but likely the issue will persist. Is it because I'm using Router.forChild()?

Comment: I've added the code to StackBlitz and the navigation works fine there, but somehow still an issue in IntelliJ. Not sure if it has to do with the Router.forChild()...

Comment: Routing issue almost fixed and also the timer issue as well. Please take the latest from repo: https://github.com/anooprvarrier/Quiz-example

Comment: I downloaded your code and I'm trying to get it to work in my IDE in my project directory, but I think you removed some code from the QuizService and I don't have the hasAnswer variable in the DI-Quiz component. I changed allQuestions to quizData.questions. Timer only seems to decrease when I click on an option and navigation is still not working. I'm going to upload the code soon to StackBlitz...

Comment: I'm reviewing the code and looking at the ScoreboardComponent and you seem to be trying to pass the value of [selectedAnswer]="answer" from ScoreComponent, but it is not defined in the ScoreComponent, showing up red in the IDE.

Comment: I added my code to StackBlitz and the timer doesn't seem to decrease, only when I click on an option and the navigation works when I click next. When I run the code in IntelliJ, I have the same problem with the timer and the navigation doesn't work. Please can you help. Thank you.

Comment: The navigation seems to work fine now in both IntelliJ and StackBlitz, but timer goes down still only when I click on an option in StackBlitz, but time doesn't budge at all in IntelliJ. Timer should run continuously in both, stopped only when the correct answer(s) are chosen.

Comment: I'm having some trouble getting the explanation text from the service to display in the di-quiz component when the question gets answered. Similarly for the correctAnswersMessage in the Question component. Also for each new question the questionText has to reset. Please see my StackBlitz. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be returning undefined when I log the explanation text to the console... also getting this error in the console: ERROR Error: correctAnswers[0].concat is not a function.

Comment: The timer seems to be working now; the problem was the ChangeDetectionStrategy was on the di-quiz component, removed it and all is fine now. Will work on the explanationText and correctAnswersMessage now.

Comment: I need the timer to stop and add quizDelay when the correct answers are selected then reset and then move to the next question. I'm going to upload my code to StackBlitz soon...

Comment: I've uploaded the code, getting an error from StaticInjectorError... also correctAnswersCount wasn't incrementing for each correct answer.

Comment: Okay it seems to work now in StackBlitz (had to use forRoot instead of forChild), and still having the issue of correctAnswersCount not incrementing, will look into tomorrow.

Comment: okay I got correctAnswersCount and time resetting between questions working. It turns out I added extra providers in child components in the scoreboard and I think that was the problem. However the time doesn't stop between questions and need to add quizDelay. Also need to work on explanationText and correctAnswersMessage.